# Access variable that update by schedule function in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a schedule to get data from DB to avoid request too many time:

```
public class A {
 private static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
  public void updateListItem() {
    items = mapper.getAllItems(); // get list item from DB
  }

  public List<Item> getItemById(String id) {
    return items.stream().filter(item -> Objects.equals(id, item.id()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

And I have an interval to get function getItemById each 1s/time with same id and it exist in DB.

> But some time, I got an empty list, though the request before return data.

Is items list was cleared before refer to  mapper.getAllItems() response? Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like method 'getItemById' used before 'updateListItem'. Please provide usage example if you think it is impossible.

I believe you can try to use 'Constructor injection' to solve the problem or may be @PostConstruct annotation.

Also note 'volatile' for 'items' property.

Example:

```
public class A {
 private volatile static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

 private Mapper mapper;

 public A(Mapper mapper){
    this.mapper = mapper;
    updateListItem();
 }

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
  public void updateListItem() {
    items = mapper.getAllItems(); // get list item from DB
  }

  public List<Item> getItemById(String id) {
    return items.stream().filter(item -> Objects.equals(id, item.id()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. List is static. remove the static keyword in variable declaration
2. Initialize the items after spring bean creation
3. Check the Predicate value Objects.equals(id,item.id)

   ```
   public class A {
       private  List<Item> items;

       @PostConstruct 
       public void init() {
          items = mapper.getAllItems();
       }

      @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
      public void updateListItem() {
        items = mapper.getAllItems(); // get list item from DB
      }

      public List<Item> getItemById(String id) {
         return items.stream().filter(item -> Objects.equals(id,item.id()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

   }
   }